# jQuery Mega Menu open and close Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a website with a custom mega menu and I have the menu working.

When you click on a link that has a dropdown with it it opens, and if you click on a different link that has a dropdown it closes the open one and opens the new one.

However I am close to screaming as I want to be able to close the open dropdown by clicking on the link of the open dropdown..

This is my jQuery so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#menu-main-menu .menu-item-has-children a').click(function(){
    $('#menu-main-menu > .menu-open').removeClass('menu-open');
    $('.menu-drop').removeClass('menu-drop');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('menu-open');
    $(this).parent('li').children('.sub-menu').addClass('menu-drop');
  });
});
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Heres the Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/CharlieH/zbtboytc/

Comment: unable to get your requirement, could you please add up a fiddle here?

Comment: Your HTML-Markup would be helpfull ...

Comment: You should check out jquery's accordion

Comment: Don't want to use an accordion for a main menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do a JsFiddle for you :

https://jsfiddle.net/zbtboytc/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $('#menu-main-menu .menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('menu-open')) {
          $(this).removeClass('menu-open');
          $(this).find('.menu-drop').removeClass('menu-drop');
      } else {
        $('.menu-open').removeClass('menu-open');
        $('.menu-drop').removeClass('menu-drop');
        $(this).addClass('menu-open');
        $(this).children('.sub-menu').addClass('menu-drop');
      }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give your HTML code ?

you can use .slideToggle() for open / close.

Like that https://jsfiddle.net/wp6zk5u9/1/

```
<button>Toggle</button>
<p>
  this text slideToggle
</p>
```

and

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

Comment: .slideToggle doesn't really serve the right purpose as I need to control the individual submenu positions on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would think not adding the menu-drop to the parent in the case of clicking a link would solve the problem.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#menu-main-menu .menu-item-has-children a').click(function(){
    $('#menu-main-menu > .menu-open').removeClass('menu-open');
    $('.menu-drop').removeClass('menu-drop');
    if(!$(this).is(a)){
      $(this).parent('li').addClass('menu-open');
      $(this).parent('li').children('.sub-menu').addClass('menu-drop');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment - I tried this and same result when clicking on the parent of the open sub menu it doesn't close.